# Beginner - "NaN" Error When Using the Following While Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Budding Javascript learner here and I am trying to get through some Nodejs tutorials. One of the tutorials has me looping through an array that always begins with two non numbers and then numbers following on from there so I am using: `array[2]` as a starting point.

```
var arrayLength = (process.argv.length);
var i = 2;
var y = 0;

while (i <= arrayLength) {
    y = y + Number(process.argv[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Example array `[ 'node', '/path/to/your/program.js', '1', '2', '3' ]`

However the variable `y` ends up being equal to `NaN`. Which, at my early stage of learning, I understand means a number tried to have a string added to it, which of course can't mathematically be done.

When I did some debugging, I found that the second to last time the `while()` is ran, it becomes `NaN`.

I'm scratching my head here on why. Any pointers?

Comment: The last element is at index `length-1` in all 0-indexed arrays; my guess is that whatever is at `i==arrayLength` is most likely `undefined` and gets cast to a `NaN`

Comment: That is correct yes. Thanks a lot for the quick aid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the loop one iteration too far. Change:

```
i <= arrayLength
```

to

```
i < arrayLength
```

(Since i starts at 0 and not 1, you only want to interate until i is one less than the length.)

Comment: Doh. Of course! If an array is 10 items long, then the last item should be fetched using `array[9]`. Thanks a bunch!